# How to address all fields in a struct like these registers?

Tags: c, struct, microcontroller, pic, mplab

If you've programmed a microcontroller, you're probably familiar with manipulating select bits of a given register, or writing a byte to the whole thing. On a PIC using C for example, I can write an entire byte to PORTA to set all the bits, or I can simply address PORTAbits.RA# to set a single bit. I'm trying to mimic the way these structs/unions are defined so I can do the same thing with a variable in my program. Specifically, when the microcontroller turns on I want to be able to reset a register I myself have defined with something like

```
REGISTER = 0;
```

versus

```
REGISTERbits.BIT0 = 0;
REGISTERbits.BIT1 = 0; 
...
//or
REGISTERbits = (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
```

etc.

Obviously the former is more elegant and saves a lot of line space. The header file of the microcontroller does it like this:

```
#ifndef __18F2550_H
#define __18F2550_H
....

extern volatile near unsigned char       LATA;
extern volatile near struct {
  unsigned LATA0:1;
  unsigned LATA1:1;
  unsigned LATA2:1;
  unsigned LATA3:1;
  unsigned LATA4:1;
  unsigned LATA5:1;
  unsigned LATA6:1;
} LATAbits;
```

...for each and every register, and registers with multiple bytes use unions of structs for their Registerbits. Since my initialization/declaration is in the main source file and not a header, I've dropped the extern and near off mine:

```
volatile unsigned char InReg;
volatile struct{
    unsigned NSENS:1;   //One magnetic sensor per direction
    unsigned SSENS:1;
    unsigned ESENS:1;
    unsigned WSENS:1;
    unsigned YBTN:1;    //One crosswalk button input per axis
    unsigned XBTN:1;    //(4 buttons tied together each)
    unsigned :2;
} InRegbits;
```

...but on compile, InReg and InRegbits are defined as two separate locations in memory, which means I can't write to InReg to change InRegbits. How do I change this so that it works? Does the one I'm trying to copy only work because it's a special microcontroller register?

Thanks for any help

Comment: I think you answered your own question: union

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
volatile union InReg {
    unsigned char InRegAll;
    struct near {
        unsigned NSENS:1;   //One magnetic sensor per direction
        unsigned SSENS:1;
        unsigned ESENS:1;
        unsigned WSENS:1;
        unsigned YBTN:1;    //One crosswalk button input per axis
        unsigned XBTN:1;    //(4 buttons tied together each)
        unsigned :2;
    } InRegbits;
}
```

Be aware that this code may not be portable.

Comment: I think this is about as good as I can get it. Turns out I don't even have to name the bit struct.

Answer (score 2):

To guarantee the same result, you'll need to have two structs within a union. The standard says that if the members of a union are structs, where the first struct member types are compatible (and relate to the same bitwidth), you can operate on any of them as the same. Otherwise accessing any union member via another is undefined behaviour.

e.g.

```
volatile union {
    volatile struct {
        unsigned int InReg;
    } InReg;
    volatile struct {
        unsigned NSENS:1;       //One magnetic sensor per direction
        unsigned SSENS:1;
        unsigned ESENS:1;
        unsigned WSENS:1;
        unsigned YBTN:1;        //One crosswalk button input per axis
        unsigned XBTN:1;        //(4 buttons tied together each)
        unsigned:2;
    } InRegbits;
} Reg_s;
```